# Getting TemplateDoesNotExist error when using bootstrap3 as template pack for crispy forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I am using django-crispy-forms for my django project, and reading in the [documentation](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#template-packs) I saw that to be able to use bootstrap3 features (like [horizontal forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html#bootstrap3-horizontal-forms)), I need to set bootstrap3 as my crispy template pack by adding this line in the settings.py of my project:

```
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3'
```

According to the docs, crispy's default is bootstrap v2. But after adding bootstrap3 in my settings, when I run my application in my development machine I get this error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /dashboard/
bootstrap3/field.html
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/dashboard/
Django Version: 1.7.3
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
bootstrap3/field.html
Exception Location: C:\Python27\VirtualEnvs\Tlaloc\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in find_template, line 136
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\VirtualEnvs\Tlaloc\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.7
```

If I remove the CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK line from my settings (as to use the defaults) or change it to look like this:

```
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap'
```

Then I don't get an error anymore, but then the form-horizontal class doesn't work in my form.

This is how my form looks like in forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.Form):
    user = forms.CharField(label='Account', max_length=15)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    # Crispy forms code
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-sm-2'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-sm-10'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset(
                '',
                'user',
                'password',
            ),
            Div(FormActions(
                Submit('continue', 'Continue', css_class='btn btn-primary'),
                Button('cancel', 'Cancel', css_class='btn btn-default',
                       data_dismiss='modal'),
                ),
                css_class='modal-footer'
                )
            )
```

And this is part of my template:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<div class="modal fade" id="adAccountModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="authenticationLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">

                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="authenticationLabel">{{ config_values.environment_name }} Environment Authentication</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Please enter the account and password that will be used to authenticate in the selected environment.</p>
                        {% crispy user_form %}
                    </div>

                    {% comment %}
                    The footer will be added through the user_form using Crispy Forms.
                    The following code will be just left here as reference. 
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Continue</button>
                    </div>
                    {% endcomment %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to put the path to crispy form's template folder in your template path in settings.py?

Comment: @dan-klasson do you mean something like this?
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), 'Whatever_the_crispy_form_template_is']
If so... do you happen to know where that template folder is?

Comment: I'd put a direct path. The location depends on your OS. But you can try searching for `django-crispy-forms/crispy_forms/templates`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that the bootstrap3 template directory didn't exist in my installation of crispy forms.

I had Crispy Forms version 1.3.2 installed on my Windows system. And looking in the project page in github I saw that the current version, which at the moment is 1.4.0, did have the \crispy_forms\templates\bootstrap3 directory. Looks like bootstrap3 template pack was introduced until this version, older versions didn't have the template pack. I upgraded to the current version, and it is now working.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurred for me when I upgraded fundamental packages (Django 1.11 to DJango 3.2, Wagtail 2.0 to Wagtail 2.16, etc). I fixed it by installing crispy_bootstrap3 separately and include it in INSTALLED_APPS. I also had to set CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3', which is odd because I have **another** project with the latest version of Django/Wagtail/Crispy Forms, and I don't need to do any of that, and I always thought bootstrap was the default template pack. Sounds a bit iffy, but please comment if you downgrade.

```
$pip install crispy-bootstrap3
```

and

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
    'crispy_forms',
    'crispy_bootstrap3',
...
]
...
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3'
```

Comment: This error happened to me when I upgraded django-crispy-forms from version 1.x to 2.0. This answer was also the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the `settings.py` file, include this:

`CRISPY_ALLOWED_TEMPLATE_PACKS = ('bootstrap', 'uni_form', 'bootstrap3', 'foundation-5')`

2. Then, in the `register.html` write this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- {% load static %} -->
<!-- {% load crispy_forms_tags %} -->

<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Django CRM - Register</title>

  <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
  <link href="{% static 'vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
  <link href="{% static 'css/sb-admin-2.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body class="bg-gradient-primary">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="card o-hidden border-0 shadow-lg my-5">
      <div class="card-body p-0">
        <!-- Nested Row within Card Body -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-2 d-none d-lg-block"></div>
          <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="p-5">
              <div class="text-center">
                <h1 class="h4 text-gray-900 mb-4">Create an Account!</h1>
              </div>
              <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{form|crispy}}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
              </form>
              <hr>
              <div class="text-center">
                <a class="small" href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
              </div>
              <div class="text-center">
                <a class="small" href="#">Already have an account? Login!</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
  <script src="{% static 'vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>

  <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
  <script src="{% static 'vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js' %}"></script>

  <!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
  <script src="{% static 'js/sb-admin-2.min.js' %}"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you please expand on WHY (i.e. what this solution does)?